# wpa_supplicant.conf escaping characters

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

`wpa_supplicant.conf` typically has double-quotes around some configuration items. Eg

```
network={
    ssid="testing"
    psk=7eb34d7f016909cc62114f2e32c8557ea8b9dc3e3f2715c351b496f750529177
}
```

What if the SSID contains unusual characters, such as the double-quote character, or non-printable binary values, or even CR or LF? Does `wpa_supplicant` have a way to escape characters, such as `\"` for double-quote or `\xEF` for binary values?

A related question is, are there any prohibited characters?

If connecting to an Enterprise network, then the password may be entered as:

```
    password="foobar"
```

and in that case, the same questions apply about escaping password characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation:

ssid: SSID (mandatory); network name in one of the optional formats:

- an ASCII string with double quotation
- a hex string (two characters per octet of SSID)
- a printf-escaped ASCII string `P"<escaped string>"`

password: Password string for EAP. This field can include either the

- plaintext password (using ASCII or hex string) or
- a NtPasswordHash (16-byte MD4 hash of password) in hash:<32 hex digits> format.

ref: https://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/wpa/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Comment: Here is an example of SSID ([]{}@$#°%^&*)-_+=<>~|:;'!!,.?/"` how to pass it in the configuration file?

Comment: simply write your ridiculously named SSID into a text file and use `od` to dump out the hex values - `tr -d '\n' < filename-containing-ssid | od -tx1 -An | tr -d ' ' | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Try to generate the PSK with `wpa_passphrase "ssid" password`, it doesn't give the same psk after escaping the special character with a slash and disabling the history expansion.

Comment: you're probably doing it wrong, can't say because I can't see what you're doing

Comment: `it doesn't give the same psk after escaping the special character with a slash and disabling the history expansion` right ... so, you do know that the psk changes if you change the ssid or password ... so `wpa_passphrase abc password` will be different to `spa_passphrase 123 password` ... so, of course if you change the SSID the passphrase changes - this illustrates why ridiculously named SSID's are a problem - why is your SSID named like that in the first place - surely nothing to do with security

Comment: In my case, my password contained both single and double quotes.  Using `P"<escaped string>"` (capital `P`) worked fine, thanks!  BTW, the string "escape" does not occur in my version of the man pages for `wpa_supplicant(.conf)`...